# Django - How can I remove some of the text displayed on the admin 'add user' page?

Tags: django, django-templates, django-views

I currently have a system where the admin is the only way to add a user to the site. All they need to do is put in thier email and they will be sent a link allowing them to create a password and set up thier account. This is all working fine.

The problem I have is shown in the image below, when the admin goes to add the user through the interface I am still greeted with the old text from the page, which I obviously do not want.

[image: Image showing the unwanted text on the Admins 'add user' page]

> "First, enter a username and password. Then, you'll be able to edit more user options."

I obviously just want this original text removed and my description about entering an email to remain.

I have found the text in the "add_form.html", but I dont believe the right solution is to delete it from there, so I am looking for a way to remove that text?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I have found the text in the "add_form.html", but I dont believe the
>   right solution is to delete it from there

You should not delete it from there, you need to override it:

- Copy original `add_form.html` template
- Edit it as you need
- Put new edited template in folder `your_project_TEMPLATES_DIRS_path_from_settings_py/admin/auth/user`

Checked it in my project, works fine.

[image]

Comment: Thank you, I managed to do it just after your original comment about overiding it, but I apreciate you adding the additional info of how to do it exactly. Thanks again!